# LinAlg package not found in Julia

Tags: julia

I just downloaded Julia 1.0.0 and have been using IJulia and the Jupyter notebook. The really good LinAlg package described online for some reason is not installed and when I try to add it through command, it says it cannot be resolved. I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or need to download something. For some reason, LinearAlgebra downloads but it is not the same thing. :(

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Base.LinAlg` module has been renamed to `LinearAlgebra` in Julia v0.7 and above. It is in the standard library, so no need to install. Just add

```
using LinearAlgebra
```

Comment: Yes, I thought this as well but a lot of the functions on https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.2/stdlib/linalg/ still don't work

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out you can adjust the version on the left!

Comment: @AakashLakshmanan Seems like that good answer deserves to be accepted?